# Python kivy listview with custom layout?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to write application in kivy. I would like it to have listview with custom row layout (label on top, below image scaled to window width and below some images, labels and button - see pic). Is it possible to do that with kivy.uix.listview? Or some other way? I was looking on docs but I couldn't find answer to my question.

[image: example]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is written in docs here: [Adapter](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.adapters.adapter.html#module-kivy.adapters.adapter)

Use either `cls` or `template` property to link a customized widget to a list view.

[Here](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.listview.html#using-a-custom-item-view-class) you can see `cls` bound to `ListItemButton`. Put your own widget in its place.